# Postgres: SequelizeDatabseError: column id does not exist

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, code-first

I am using Postgresql with code-first approach in my Node.JS project. Some of the tables were already there in the inherited code. There is a table called user_games storing the information about which user is playing which games. Model of the table has been defined as follows:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require( 'sequelize' );
module.exports = ( sequelize, DataTypes ) => {
  class UserGames extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate( models ) {
      // define association here
      UserGames.belongsTo( models.Game, {
        as: 'Games',
        foreignKey: 'game_id',
        onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
        onUpdate: 'NO ACTION'
      } );

      UserGames.belongsTo( models.User, {
        as: 'User',
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        onDelete: 'NO ACTION',
        onUpdate: 'NO ACTION'
      } );

      UserGames.hasMany( models.GameUrl, {
        foreignKey: 'game_id'
      } );
    }
  }

  UserGames.init( {
    user_game_id: { // eslint-disable-line camelcase
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    user_id: DataTypes.STRING, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    games_gamer_id: DataTypes.STRING, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
    game_id: DataTypes.UUID // eslint-disable-line camelcase
  }, {
    sequelize,
    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
    modelName: 'UserGames',
    tableName: 'user_games',
  } );
  return UserGames;
};
```

Things were working fine but suddenly the following (and other related) code started complaining "column UserGames.id does not exist" :

```
models.Game.findAndCountAll( {
include: [ {
  model: models.UserGames,
  as: 'UserGames',
  where: { user_id: userId }, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
} ],
attributes: [ 'name', 'description_text', 'icon_url' ],
order: [
  [ 'name', 'ASC' ]
],
```

} );

So, we had to modify 'include' part for the table user_games to specify the attributes explicitly as below:

```
include: [ {
  model: models.UserGames,
  as: 'UserGames',
  where: { user_id: userId }, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
  attributes: [ 'game_id' ], //otherwise it will look for 'id' field also.
} ],
```

As shown in the model definition, the table contains a column user_game_id as the primary key and as I mentioned, things were working fine a few days ago. So, I am not able to understand the reason for the error. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Edit: Here is the game model:

```
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require( 'sequelize' );
module.exports = ( sequelize, DataTypes ) => {
  class Game extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate( models ) {
      // define association here
      Game.belongsTo( models.Partner, {
        as: 'Partner',
        foreignKey: 'partner_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      } );
      Game.hasMany( models.UserGames, {
        as: 'UserGames',
        foreignKey: 'game_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      } );
      Game.hasMany( models.GameAsset, {
        as: 'GameAssetDetails',
        foreignKey: 'game_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      } );
      Game.hasMany( models.GameUrl, {
        as: 'GameUrlDetails',
        foreignKey: 'game_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      } );
      Game.hasMany( models.GameTestingComment, {
        foreignKey: 'game_id',
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
      } );
      Game.hasMany( models.OfferSchedule, {
        foreignKey: 'game_id'
      } );
    }
  }

  Game.init( {
    game_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    partner_id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      allowNull: false
    },
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    description_text: DataTypes.TEXT,
    icon_url: DataTypes.STRING,
    status: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: [ "1", "2", "3", "4" ],
      defaultValue: "1",
      comment: "1 => 'In Development', 2 => 'Submit for Approval', 3 => 'Approved', 4 => 'Rejected'",
    },
    approved_date: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    submitted_date: {
      allowNull: true,
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    is_active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt',
    modelName: 'Game',
    tableName: 'game',
  } );
  return Game;
};
```

Comment: show `Game` associations

Comment: @Anatoly I have updated the question to add the `Game` model. Please check.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. Please show the generated SQL query where you get the error about `id`

Comment: @Anatoly, here is the generated SQL query:

`SELECT "Game"."name", "Game"."description_text", "Game"."icon_url", "UserGames"."user_game_id" AS "UserGames.user_game_id", "UserGames"."user_id" AS "UserGames.user_id", "UserGames"."games_gamer_id" AS "UserGames.games_gamer_id", "UserGames"."game_id" AS "UserGames.game_id", "UserGames"."createdAt" AS "UserGames.createdAt", "UserGames"."updatedAt" AS "UserGames.updatedAt", "UserGames"."id" AS "UserGames.id" FROM "game" AS "Game" LEFT OUTER JOIN "user_games" AS "UserGames" ON "Game"."game_id" = "UserGames"."game_id" ORDER BY "Game"."name" ASC;`

Comment: It's better to add SQL as formated block in the post. It's hard to read it in comments

Comment: Can you run `UserGames.findAll({})` and show SQL as well (formatted and in the post).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, we are able to figure out the source of issue. A few days back, one of the developers in the team added the wrong association. He set 'id' column of UserGames as foreign key in other table though the UserGames did not have 'id' column at all. Below is the faulty code:

```
static associate( models ) {
  GameProducts.hasMany( models.UserGames, {
    as: 'SubscriptionPlans',
    sourceKey: "game_product_id",
    foreignKey: 'id' //Faulty code. UserGames does not have 'id' column
  } );
}
```